# wp_enqueue_script( ) function parameters in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making my first steps coding. I already made some courses of php in internet and now I am trying to continue learning from the practice while I am making a Wordpress theme.

I made a child theme from an existing theme and there is something that I dont understand in this function:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20150315', true );
```

I found this in the site of wordpress:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

I understand that $handle is the name of the script file, but i have to put that name in some place in the script file to make my code work?

Then i know that I should write `get_template_directory_uri()`, the source, and write `array(jquery)` in the case that it is a jquery file but what means `'20150315', true` . What means that number? Why I have to write `true` at the end?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ explains all the parameters

Answer (score 0):

### Parameters

**$handle**
*(string) (Required)* Name of the script. Should be unique.

**$src**
*(string) (Optional)* Full URL of the script, or path of the script relative to the WordPress root directory.
*Default value: false*

**$deps**
*(array) (Optional)* An array of registered script handles this script depends on.
*Default value: array()*

**$ver**
*(string|bool|null) (Optional)* String specifying script version number, if it has one, which is added to the URL as a query string for cache busting purposes. If version is set to false, a version number is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. If set to null, no version is added.
*Default value: false*

**$in_footer**
*(bool) (Optional)* Whether to enqueue the script before `</body>` instead of in the `<head>`. Default 'false'.
*Default value: false*

So for your example:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20150315', true );
```

Which breaks down to:

```
$handle = 'twentyfourteen-script'
$src = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js'
$deps = array( 'jquery' )
$ver = '20150315'
$in_footer = true
```